# Unpack and build back wix msi installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm just trying to unpack a Wix installer (`*.msi`) to get its `wxs` and build it back to `*.msi`.
I'm doing the following:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\dark.exe" installer.msi -x out 
[...]

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\candle.exe" *.wxs -o obj\ -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\WixUtilExtension.dll"
[...]

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\light.exe" obj\*.wixobj -o bin\installerModVersion.msi -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\WixUtilExtension.dll"
Windows Installer XML Toolset Linker version 3.11.2.4516
Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved.

C:\ProgramData\[...]\installer.wxs(172) : error LGHT0130 : The primary key 'INSTALLFOLDER/CreateFolder//[WIX_ACCOUNT_LOCALSYSTEM]' is duplicated in table 'LockPermissions'.  Please remove one of the entries or rename a part of the primary key to avoid the collision.
```

So the error just happens in the last step:

> C:\ProgramData[...]\installer.wxs(172) : error LGHT0130 : The primary
> key 'INSTALLFOLDER/CreateFolder//[WIX_ACCOUNT_LOCALSYSTEM]' is
> duplicated in table 'LockPermissions'.  Please remove one of the
> entries or rename a part of the primary key to avoid the collision.

This is the code round line `172`:

```
                <Directory Id="drivers" Name="drivers">
                    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="ProgramName" ShortName="mn7flurp">
                        <Component Id="InstallFolderPermissions" Guid="{F5BC8C33-8B18-4FE8-8D5D-555B766161FD}" KeyPath="yes" Win64="yes">
                            <CreateFolder Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
                           line 172 ------>     <Permission User="[WIX_ACCOUNT_LOCALSYSTEM]" Read="yes" SpecificRightsAll="yes" ReadAttributes="yes" WriteAttributes="yes" ReadExtendedAttributes="yes" WriteExtendedAttributes="yes" CreateFile="yes" CreateChild="yes" DeleteChild="yes" Traverse="yes" GenericAll="yes" />
                                <Permission User="[WIX_ACCOUNT_ADMINISTRATORS]" GenericAll="yes" />
```

What am I doing wrong? I am not modifying anything of the created by `dark.exe` `wxs` file.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you decompiled you did not include the Util extension, but then you included it when you compiled. That definition lives in the Util extension so your decompiled output has a duplicate which collides.

Add `-ext WixUtilExtension.dll` to your dark.exe command line.

Comment: I tried but I get this error:
```
dark.exe : error DARK0126 : The extension 'Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Extensions.UtilExtension' contains a defintion for table 'EventManifest' that collides with a previously loaded table definition.  Please remove one of the conflicting extensions or rename one of the tables to avoid the collision.
```

Comment: One problem solved, new problem revealed.